# Ruby: Round number down to nearest number based on arbitrary list of numbers

Tags: ruby, arrays, rounding

Say I have an array of integers:

```
arr = [0,5,7,8,11,16]
```

and I have another integer:

```
n = 6
```

I need a function that rounds down to the nearest number from the array:

```
foo(n) #=> 5
```

As you can see, the numbers do not have a fixed pattern. What's an elegant way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Of course, your statement n = 6.5 does not define an integer.  I expect that is a typo on your part.

Comment: yea my bad. i was deciding if i wanted to ask about floats/fixnums, etc and went for what really mattered, which was the algorithm.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use [**`select`**](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M003125) followed by [**`max`**](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M003134):

```
arr = [0,5,7,8,11,16]
puts arr.select{|item| item < 6}.max
```

Result:

```
5
```

This runs in linear time and doesn't require that the array is sorted.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using relatively small arrays (and so not overly worried about efficiency), then this should work fine:

```
def down_to_array num, arr
  arr.select{|y| y < num}.sort_by{|z| num-z }.first
end
```

E.g:

```
myarr = [0,5,7,8,11,16]
puts down_to_array 6.5, myarr #=> 5
```

Comment: Nice answer. I would like just to add this link http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M003120 which is how you can run a benchmark on sort_by to check if it's a good solution with your arrays.