# Round to nearest arbitrary number from list

Tags: r

I'm basically looking for a way to do a variation of [this Ruby script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160502/ruby-round-number-down-to-nearest-number-based-on-arbitrary-list-of-numbers) in R.
I have an **arbitrary list of numbers** (steps of a moderator for a regression plot in this case) which have unequal distances from each other, and I'd like to round values which are within a range around these numbers to the nearest number in the list. 
The ranges don't overlap.

```
arbitrary.numbers <- c(4,10,15) / 10
numbers <- c(16:1 / 10, 0.39, 1.45)
range <- 0.1
```

Expected output:

```
numbers
## 1.6 1.5 1.4 1.3 1.2 1.1 1.0 0.9 0.8 0.7 0.6 0.5 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.1 0.39 1.45
round_to_nearest_neighbour_in_range(numbers,arbitrary.numbers,range)
## 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.3 1.2 1.0 1.0 1.0 0.8 0.7 0.6 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.2 0.1 0.4 1.5
```

I've got a little helper function that might do for my specific problem, but it's not very flexible and it contains a loop. I can post it here, but I think a real solution would look completely different.

### The different answers timed for speed (on a million numbers)

```
> numbers = rep(numbers,length.out = 1000000)
> system.time({ mvg.round(numbers,arbitrary.numbers,range) })[3]
elapsed 
  0.067 
> system.time({ rinker.loop.round(numbers,arbitrary.numbers,range) })[3]
elapsed 
  0.289 
> system.time({ rinker.round(numbers,arbitrary.numbers,range) })[3]
elapsed 
  1.403 
> system.time({ nograpes.round(numbers,arbitrary.numbers,range) })[3]
elapsed 
  1.971 
> system.time({ january.round(numbers,arbitrary.numbers,range) })[3]
elapsed 
  16.12 
> system.time({ shariff.round(numbers,arbitrary.numbers,range) })[3]
elapsed 
15.833 
> system.time({ mplourde.round(numbers,arbitrary.numbers,range) })[3]
elapsed 
  9.613 
> system.time({ kohske.round(numbers,arbitrary.numbers,range) })[3]
elapsed 
 26.274
```

MvG's function is the fastest, about 5 times faster than Tyler Rinker's second function.

Comment: Downvoter, any comment as to why?

Comment: Generally benchmarking isn't done in the way you've performed it.  You'd want to use the benchmark or rbenchmark package.

Comment: @TylerRinker I think in this case, the `rbenchmark` package would be overkill. The differences in times are orders of magnitude.

Comment: @nograpes I'm not quite sure what you mean by "the differences in times are orders of magnitude", but I think I may disagree.  It's likely your response will come in first but it would be interesting to see how january, shariff and mplourde's compare.  We have no idea from one run what's going on.  Maybe this is an old computer, low memory and slow processor and Ruben just happened to also be playing Super Tetris 2000 while running the test.  The replication gives us information not just on the fastest solution here but which chunks may serve us well in future programming needs.

Comment: When the differences in time are orders of magnitude, I'd say my choice makes sense. But rinker.round is of course a new contender and dare I say, it might the fastest :-).

Comment: rinker.round will be slow I already know that as nograpes is a lot closer to being vectorized, his does less computation overall.  It was well done.

Comment: Reading Ruben's comments in nograpes I now see he performed this on 1 million numbers.  Withdraw my claim :)

Comment: @Tyler You may not know, but your function ain't slow. Credit where credit is due, I guess? I interrupted the rbenchmark test when i read your last comment, because it kept me from playing Super Tetris.

Comment: @TylerRinker What I meant by "orders of magnitude" is that the my solution was roughly 10 times faster than other solutions (except yours). In such cases, even very rough comparisons, with only one run, will probably be sufficient to conclude that the technique is fundamentally faster (than techniques other than yours).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yet another solution using `findInterval`:

```
arbitrary.numbers<-sort(arbitrary.numbers)          # need them sorted
range <- range*1.000001                             # avoid rounding issues
nearest <- findInterval(numbers, arbitrary.numbers - range) # index of nearest
nearest <- c(-Inf, arbitrary.numbers)[nearest + 1]  # value of nearest
diff <- numbers - nearest                           # compute errors
snap <- diff <= range                               # only snap near numbers
numbers[snap] <- nearest[snap]                      # snap values to nearest
print(numbers)
```

The `nearest` in the above code is not really mathematically the nearest number. Instead, it is the largest arbitrary number such that `nearest[i] - range <= numbers[i]`, or equivalently `nearest[i] <= numbers[i] + range`. So in one go we find the largest arbitrary number which is either in the snapping range for a given input number, or still too small for that. For this reason, we only need to check one way for `snap`. No absolute value required, and even the squaring from a previous revision of this post was unneccessary.

Thanks to [Interval search on a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11705765/interval-search-on-a-data-frame) for the pointer at `findInterval`, as I found it there before recognizing it in the [answer by nograpes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12861810).

If, in contrast to your original question, you had overlapping ranges, you could write things like this:

```
arbitrary.numbers<-sort(arbitrary.numbers)        # need them sorted
range <- range*1.000001                           # avoid rounding issues
nearest <- findInterval(numbers, arbitrary.numbers) + 1 # index of interval
hi <- c(arbitrary.numbers, Inf)[nearest]          # next larger
nearest <- c(-Inf, arbitrary.numbers)[nearest]    # next smaller
takehi <- (hi - numbers) < (numbers - nearest)    # larger better than smaller
nearest[takehi] <- hi[takehi]                     # now nearest is really nearest
snap <- abs(nearest - numbers) <= range           # only snap near numbers
numbers[snap] <- nearest[snap]                    # snap values to nearest
print(numbers)
```

In this code, `nearest`really ends up being the nearest number. This is achieved by considering *both* endpoints of every interval. In spirit, this is very much like the [version by nograpes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12861810), but it avoids using `ifelse` and `NA`, which should benefit performance as it reduces the number of branching instructions.

Comment: Wow! This is roughly 16 times faster than Rinker's solution AND it's  commented.

Answer (score 9):

A vectorized solution, without any `apply` family functions or loops:

The key is `findInterval`, which finds the "space" in `arbitrary.numbers` where each element in `numbers` is "between". So, `findInterval(6,c(2,4,7,8))` returns `2`, because `6` is between the 2nd and 3rd index of `c(2,4,7,8)`.

```
# arbitrary.numbers is assumed to be sorted.
# find the index of the number just below each number, and just above.
# So for 6 in c(2,4,7,8) we would find 2 and 3.
low<-findInterval(numbers,arbitrary.numbers) # find index of number just below
high<-low+1 # find the corresponding index just above.

# Find the actual absolute difference between the arbitrary number above and below.
# So for 6 in c(2,4,7,8) we would find 2 and 1. 
# (The absolute differences to 4 and 7).
low.diff<-numbers-arbitrary.numbers[ifelse(low==0,NA,low)]
high.diff<-arbitrary.numbers[ifelse(high==0,NA,high)]-numbers

# Find the minimum difference. 
# In the example we would find that 6 is closest to 7, 
# because the difference is 1.
mins<-pmin(low.diff,high.diff,na.rm=T) 
# For each number, pick the arbitrary number with the minimum difference.
# So for 6 pick out 7.
pick<-ifelse(!is.na(low.diff) & mins==low.diff,low,high)

# Compare the actual minimum difference to the range. 
ifelse(mins<=range+.Machine$double.eps,arbitrary.numbers[pick],numbers)
# [1] 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.3 1.2 1.0 1.0 1.0 0.8 0.7 0.6 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.2 0.1 0.4 1.5
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the fastest solution, by far. For 1 million numbers it takes ca. 0.8, while the others take 14 (shariff/january) -25 (kohske)

Comment: I don't get how it works exactly yet, but I'd like to, so comments would be nice! Not relevant for me, but maybe for others:  `arbitrary.numbers = sort(arbitrary.numbers)` is needed for findInterval to work.

Comment: Such beautiful code comments… I'm really being spoiled with good answers here.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you want?

```
> idx <- abs(outer(arbitrary.numbers, numbers, `-`)) <= (range+.Machine$double.eps)
> rounded <- arbitrary.numbers[apply(rbind(idx, colSums(idx) == 0), 2, which)]
> ifelse(is.na(rounded), numbers, rounded)
 [1] 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.3 1.2 1.0 1.0 1.0 0.8 0.7 0.6 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.2 0.1 0.4 1.5
```

Answer (score 2):

Please note that due to rounding errors (most likely), I use range = 0.1000001 to achieve the expected effect.

```
range <- range + 0.0000001

blah <- rbind( numbers, sapply( numbers, function( x ) abs( x - arbitrary.numbers ) ) )
ff <- function( y ) { if( min( y[-1] ) <= range + 0.000001 ) arbitrary.numbers[ which.min( y[ -1 ] ) ] else  y[1]  }
apply( blah, 2, ff )
```

Answer (score 2):

This is still shorter:

```
sapply(numbers, function(x) ifelse(min(abs(arbitrary.numbers - x)) > 
range + .Machine$double.eps, x, arbitrary.numbers[which.min
(abs(arbitrary.numbers - x))] ))
```

Thanks @MvG

Comment: Hint: Use `sapply` to avoid the `unlist`.

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
arb.round <- function(numbers, arbitrary.numbers, range) {
    arrnd <- function(x, ns, r){ 
        ifelse(abs(x - ns) <= range +.00000001, ns, x)
    }
    lapply(1:length(arbitrary.numbers), function(i){
            numbers <<- arrnd(numbers, arbitrary.numbers[i], range)
        }
    )
    numbers
}

arb.round(numbers, arbitrary.numbers, range)
```

Yields:

```
> arb.round(numbers, arbitrary.numbers, range)
[1] 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.3 1.2 1.0 1.0 1.0 0.8 0.7 0.6 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.2 0.1 0.4 1.5
```

EDIT: I removed the return call at the end of the function as it's not necessary adn can burn time.

EDIT:  I think a loop will be even faster here:

```
loop.round <- function(numbers, arbitrary.numbers, range) {
    arrnd <- function(x, ns, r){ 
        ifelse(abs(x - ns) <= range +.00000001, ns, x)
    }
    for(i in seq_along(arbitrary.numbers)){
            numbers <- arrnd(numbers, arbitrary.numbers[i], range)
    }
    numbers
}
```

Comment: That's not the correct solution, as can be seen from your own output.